# IBM IIDR for kafka - User Exits are not clickable

Tags: apache-kafka, cdc, ibm-infosphere

I am currently using IIDR v11.4.0.3 linux x86.

Subscription setup - using kafkaproducer.properties file to setup my kafka properties.

After setting up the subscription and confirming that replication is working, despite stopping the replication, i am still able to select the User Exits option to allow subscription level User Exits.

Appreciate any advice on what can be the potential issue.

[screenshot of User Exits button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw24O.png)

Answer (score 0):

In past instances when I have seen this, the version of access server and MC were older than when the KCOP feature was introduced to the Kafka target.  Essentially the management console is on a version that does not realize User Exits for KCOPs are a valid option.

It's unlikely the issue but you'll also want to confirm the actual version of your IDR Kafka target by considering the additional version level information.  It should be something like this... IDR 11.4.0.3-5566.

For reference, A link to release notes is here (showing latest version of the IDR Engine code etc).  https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/release-notes-iidr-114-replication-engines-linux-unix-and-windows

I would try moving up to a recent version of MC and access server and recreate the subscription (just for thoroughness but most likely not necessary).

If this doesn't resolve the issue, IBM's support tickets will definitely be able to help.

(I'm the owner of the IBM IDR Kafka target in development).

Cheers.

Comment: @Lim Gangyi   Did this help you out and resolve your issue?

Comment: thanks for getting back and apologies for the late reply.

I managed to find a workaround in which to access the user exit from the window subscription tab. Nonetheless you are spot-on on the possible root cause, in which my management console version is currently lower than the IDR kafka replication engine.

p.s just watched your kafka summit presentation. Really cool stuff... even cooler that you helped out here :)